# Translation of "man gönnt sich ja sonst nichts"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I got a bottle of Black-Wood whisky for Christmas and this phrase is on the pamphlet included. 
From my searching online, it might mean something like *my only vice* or *it’s my one and only treat* but I thought you all here could provide better context.

[image: black-wood]

Comment: https://www.dict.cc/?s=Man+g%C3%B6nnt+sich+ja+sonst+nichts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common expression. The phrase *sich etwas gönnen* means to allow oneself something, in the sense of an indulgence. The word *man* is an indefinite pronoun. The sentence

> Man gönnt sich sonst nichts.

means

> One does not indulge in anything else.

or maybe better

> We do not have other indulgences.

The word *ja* is here used as modal particle which change the intent of that statement into something like

> Since we do not have any other indulgences...

The *we* here refers to someone drinking the whisky. The sentence is used as a jocular excuse for that one indulgence.

I am sure that there are better ways to express these things in English.

Comment: I'd use "I" or "you" instead of "we". In this sentence, "man" refers to the reader of the pamphlet, not to the whisky destillers.

Comment: @Uwe, right, I will point that out. Still *man* less personal than *ich* and makes it sound like a more general statement, and I wanted to convey this by using the plural in English.

Comment: ok, makes sense.

Comment: in my experience, when someone uses this phrase it is usually not without some irony, I think this information is missing here

Comment: I disagree with your explanation of the particle *ja* - I rather perceive it as a short form of saying "as you all know".

Comment: @fifaltra, I had hoped that "jocular" makes that clear, but probably not sufficiently.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, ich verstehe das "ja" als "es ist ja schon so, dass", mit impliziertem "daher kann man zumindest...".

Answer (score 2):

**Man gönnt sich ja sonst nichts!** is originally a commercial slagon from 1987 of another alcoholic drink "Malteserkreuz Akvavit/Danish Danisco" ([1](https://de.wikiquote.org/wiki/Werbespr%C3%BCche)).

The meaning is that **you should/can allow yourself some pleasure (by drinking this alcohol)**. However, nowadays the slogan has always an ironic touch. Common figures are, for example, an alcoholic who say the slogan several times a day (and obviously allows himself too much). Or a very rich person who already owns several cars, buys a new one saying "Man gönnt sich ja sonst nichts!".

During my research I also found *Man muss sich auch mal was Gutes gönnen. (A bit of what you fancy does you good.)*, which is at least in the German translation close to the slogan *Man gönnt sich ja sonst nichts!*.

Answer (score 2):

*Man gönnt sich sonst nichts* would mean *One doesn't allow oneself anything else*, or maybe more naturally *There is nothing else one allows oneself*.

The *ja* weakens the sentences in a way that what is said in the sentence is a known fact, so a possible translation is:

*As there is nothing else one allows oneself*.

Comment: Thank you for editing. Usually it will however not help much once the community voted for deletion, as then the question will no longer be visible to most of us. We won't get noticed on any such edit. I stumbled on it by mere accident. So next time you may better just write a new answer instead where you are welcome to include any improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, at first look, that the phrase would ***literally*** mean:

> One just grants himself/herself nothing else.

**Man** is an indefinite pronoun that means "one", "they" or "you" and it is construed as a 3rd person singular. It is the subject of the sentence and it refers to the reader of this pamphlet.

**Gönnt** is the 3rd singular person (man + gönnt) of reflexive form of (sich + verb) **[gönnen](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=g%C3%B6nnen&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on)** verb. Here, *sich etwas gönnen* means to allow or grant oneself something, as gratification or something pleasurable.

**Ja**, that basically means "Yes" in German, is an adverb and it is used here as intensifier, to emphasize something that is a known fact (the whisky is so good that you don't need anything else). As intensifier, it could mean "really", "just", "of course" and so on.

**Sonst** is an adverb that means "normally", "otherwise", or "else".

**Nichts** is an indefinite pronoun that means "nothing". In this case, together with "sonst" (sonst + nichts), it means "nothing else".

Basically, the phrase would mean that there's just nothing else better than this whisky for you.

Considering the context (you drink some whiskey for your own pleasure), I would say that the phrase means:

> Of course, one doesn't indulge in anything else.

or

> One doesn't indulge in anything else, as you know.

or

> Indulge yourself in nothing else.

I hope that the meaning of the phrase is clear enough. Most probably, there are better ways in English than mine to express in a clearer and more exact way the meaning of this phrase.

Comment: @Downvoter Dear downvoter, I would like to know the reason of your downvote. Downvoting without any explanation I think that's not correct. We all are here to learn something new and improve ourselves.

Comment: Although I am not the one who downvoted your answer, I would suggest that the first part of the answer was considered too literal, analysing every single word. And as a native Austrian I feel like your suggestion of a meaning is incorrect.

Comment: The suggestions at the bottom don't carry the meaning of the original phrase.

Comment: @jera Thank you for your suggestions. About the first part of the answer, my first phrase was indeed _the phrase would literally mean_. I added this to highlight the fact the first translation I did was very literal. After that, I added the analysis. I am aware of the fact my suggestion is not perfect (I am not a native speaker of both English and German). I will do my best to improve the answer.

Comment: @Burki Thanks! I will do my best to improve the answer.

Comment: @Burki I've updated the answer. What do you think of it?

Comment: @jera I've updated the answer. What do you think of it?

Comment: I would still consider the last two translations incorrect. Other than that it is ok.

Comment: @jera Right, I removed them.

Comment: Translation of such a phrase is hard and next to impossible. I've looked at translations found on the Internet and I like the translations using "to treat oneself to". "treat yourself to nothing else" in a verbatim sense and, more loosely, "treat yourself to the good things of life". In respect to your answer, I don't think that it's a good idea to look at every word when it comes to a saying or fixed expression. Besides, the word "ja" is a modal particle and doesn't really add any value to the sentence.

Comment: @Em1 Yes, I indeed realized that the translation is rather hard..Well, I didn't know it was something well known that is considered as a saying or fixed expression (in this case a known slogan). Iris posted a very interesting link about commercial slogans, I'll have a look at it. Thanks for your suggestion anyway. Why does "ja" not add any value to this sentence? I have read texts and sentences with this word when it's usually needed to intensify something that is known, as it seems in this case. Is there any exception?